# Assets Catalog and Parse Libraries randomly deleted in XCode 7

Tags: ios, parse-platform, xcode7, assets

Whenever I close XCode or even Discard Changes, all the items in the assets folder are removed completely, and my Parse.com library is no longer recognized.  It's not the end of the world, since it takes maybe 10 or 15 minutes to put them all back in place.  But still, this is time that I'd rather spend being productive rather than redoing things I've already done.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?  Anyone figured out how to resolve the issue?